# Does $\tilde{\mathrm E}_{6,3}^{(2)6}$ exist over a p-adic field?

Tags: gr.group-theory, reductive-groups, p-adic-groups

Does a form of $\tilde{\mathrm E}_6^{(2)}$ with this Satake-Tits diagram exist over a p-adic field?
[image: 1]

Comment: Maybe the tables of Tits will help you: J. Tits, Classification of algebraic semisimple groups, Proc. Symp Pure Math vol. 9, American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1966, pp. 33–62.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi I have seen those tables. They only list the finite-dimensional indices, although they do confirm that removing any white node leaves a diagram that is still valid.